# Validating fields on REST endpoint

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have an endpoint that when called should either update or create a user's profile. Inside this endpoint are 3 fields that need to be created or updated `(avatar, bio, gender)` Currently, I'm working with an `UpdateAPIView` like so:

```
class UpdateOrCreateProfile(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
```

The serializer class looks like this:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

This works good, however, the validation is not working correctly. The form that is displayed has a `clean_avatar` function that does not accept images under 200x200 px. Like so:

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    avatar = forms.ImageField(required=False, widget=forms.FileInput)
    bio = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3, "placeholder": "Bio"}), max_length=200,
                          required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['avatar', 'bio', 'gender']

    def clean_avatar(self):
        picture = self.cleaned_data.get("avatar")
        if picture:
            w, h = get_image_dimensions(picture)
            if w < 200:
                raise forms.ValidationError("The image is %i pixel wide. It's supposed to be more than 200px" % w)
            if h < 200:
                raise forms.ValidationError("The image is %i pixel high. It's supposed to be 200px" % h)
        return picture
```

How can I make it so that the same validation that happens on the form, also happens in my endpoint?

Comment: I think you want this [DRF Custom validator](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#function-based)

Comment: you should pass your validator in your ImageField [Ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/validators/)

Comment: @KhashayarGhamati Very interesting, thank you for that!

Comment: i think what you are looking for is [field level validation in serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a validate_avtar method.It work as form clean method work.

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Profile
      fields = '__all__'

   def validate_avatar(self, picture):
     if picture:
        w, h = get_image_dimensions(picture)
        if w < 200:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("The image is %i pixel wide. It's supposed to be more than 200px" % w)
        if h < 200:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("The image is %i pixel high. It's supposed to be 200px" % h)
     return picture
```